# ReadExisting() in Serial Port throws I/O exception

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

We are reading Data from the SerialPort in .Net 2.0. But before reading we make sure that there is nothing in the Serial Port. So we are waiting until the serial Port In-Buffer is Empty.

Here is the Code:

```
SerialCommunicationPort.SerialPort.BaudRate = 300;
SerialCommunicationPort.SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
SerialCommunicationPort.SerialPort.StopBits = 1;
SerialCommunicationPort.SerialPort.DataBits = 7;
SerialCommunicationPort.SerialPort.ReadTimeout = 1;
SerialCommunicationPort.SerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
SerialCommunicationPort.SerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
SerialCommunicationPort.SerialPort.WriteTimeout = 1500; 

do
{
    strTempRecv = SerialCommunicationPort.SerialPort.ReadExisting();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTempRecv))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        intTimeOut++;
    }
    else
    {
        intTimeOut = 0;
    }
} while (intTimeOut < 50);
```

If the external device is sending data to the serial port at some Baud rate say 4800, our application is receiving that at 300. After some time the Do-While loop above throws this IO Exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

   at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.BeginReadCore(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 numBytes, AsyncCallback userCallback, Object stateObject)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Int32 timeout)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.ReadExisting()
```

Comment: Why is your application not receiving the data at the same baud rate that is being sent at.

Comment: We are sending the Command to the external device and receiving data at a Specific Baud rate say 4800..In case we close our application in between the device will be still sending the data..At this time if we run our application again and open the serial port..it will be still receiving the data which is of no use for us..We have to discard it..For that Purpose we are waiting until the Serial Port Buffer is empty..So we have chosen 300 as the Baud Rate and we are simply polling the Buffer to see if its empty.when we start polling ..after sometime we get that exception.

Comment: Take a look at this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596726/compact-framework-serial-port-and-balance/596773#596773.  I believe the problem you are having is because the Baud Rates are mismatched you are decoding garbage.

Comment: There might be an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3177429/1236397